# What's the fastest way to move on foot in low gravity

Tags: gravity, combat

Say you're in a combat situation on a low gravity world and you're trying to move from one bit of cover to the next as quickly as possible. How would you do that?

Comment: I don' thave time to research this as an answer properly, but Mythbusters demonstrated that skipping was actually the most effective mode of transportation in moon-level gravitational fields.

Comment: This is rather vague as exactly what you'd do depend on the exact tactical situation - terrain, what type of fire and detection equipment is being used, what gravity exactly, what other equipment is needed to complete the mission and has to be carried.  One simple answer might be to simply carry cover with you - low gravity means a good shield can be carried which would be too heavy on Earth, but OK in low gravity - but, again, this depends on what kind of cover you require and from what armaments or detectors.  It's complicated - combat is.

Answer (score 3):

**How low is low?**  If we are talking about an asteroid with barely any gravity, then the easiest way to do it would be to use your arms to control yourself.  It would be dangerous in a combat situation to not be holding on to the ground at all times, since you might fly too far above the ground and take minutes to fall back.

If we're talking about a world like the moon then it would depend on what you're wearing.  The jump-skip of the Apollo astronauts was the simplest way to get around (and this was tested specifically on Apollo 11) but it was also due to the stiff space suit - the astronauts couldn't easily bend their legs or do the standard motions required to walk on Earth.  If you are in relatively mobile clothing/can breathe without equipment, it may not be true.

Either way, you don't want to jump for cover like you can on Earth, since falling might take too long and you'll just be hanging in the air.  So the question shouldn't really be about speed but about safety.  On such a world, you'd probably want to stay on the ground as much as possible with very little chance of bouncing or jumping.  So the safest way is probably to remain flat and crawl, perhaps roll, but never jump.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming gravity as low as Luna or less, the *fastest* way from one covered position to another would be the hardest jump you can manage, on a direct line (or the lowest, flattest arc your muscles or any augmentation available can give you).  Think of it like microgravity -- you can either go from handhold to handhold, or you can launch yourself across the intervening space.  One is secure; the other is *fast*.

The more gravity you have to deal with, the more modification this will need, but on Ceres (about 3% G) you can treat anything other than sitting still as microgravity.  Any other asteroid in our system will be lower gravity than that.  On Luna and most of the other large moons, you'd have to account for gravity, but if you're in a situation where you have freedom of movement, that isn't that hard (providing you've trained or lived in that environment long enough for your reflexes to adjust).

If you have as much gravity as Mars or Mercury, your movement would be more like on Earth -- essentially running -- but with a little more "bounce" that you'd have to be careful of.